# How to take screenshot with small size in libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx, screenshot

In my Full HD Nexus 7 2013, when using this method provided by libgdx: [link](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Take-a-Screenshot), the size of the result png screenshot file is **8.35Mb**. But if I hold down Volume down + power to capture screen, I get a png with size of only about **200Kb**, which is extremely smaller, and a lot faster to create. Is there anyway to produce such small size screenshot in libgdx?